# Trouble reading and binding yml data in ruby

Tags: ruby, erb

I have a yaml file that includes the following:

```
:common
  :substitue
    :foo: fee
```

I read this data like:

```
data = YAML.load(erb_data[File.basename(__FILE__, '.*')].result(binding))

common = data[:common]

def substitute_if_needed(original_value)
    mapping = common.dig(:substitue, original_value)
    if mapping.nil? ? original_value : mapping
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't do the substitution that I want. I want to call `substitute_if_needed('foo')` and get 'fee' back. I also want to call `substitute_if_needed('bar')` and get 'bar' back.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code snippet: `if mapping.nil? ? original_value : mapping`.  Looks like you just need to delete the `if` since the ternary *is* the if logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. YAML example looks broken. The proper one should looks like:

```
common:
  substitute:
    foo: fee
```

2. You're trying to fetch `common` key in `common = data[:common]` using a symbol as a key, but it should be a string (`data["common"]`). Also, I'd say it's a bad idea to spilt fetching logic into two pieces - first extract "common" outside of `substitute_when_needed` and then `dig` into it inside.
3. `if` statement is broken. It should be either proper `if` or proper ternary operator.

Fixing all this gives us something like (I've just replaced a file with StringIO for convenience - to make the snippet executable as is):

```
yaml = StringIO.new(<<~DATA)
  common:
    substitute:
      foo: fee
DATA

def substitute_if_needed(data, original_value)
  mapping = data.dig("common", "substitute", original_value)
  mapping.nil? ? original_value : mapping
end

data = YAML.load(yaml)

substitute_if_needed(data, "foo") # => "fee"
substitute_if_needed(data, "bar") # => "bar"
```